# Remove Forced Login / Sign Up

Tags: customer-account, login, remove, account

I've a personalised board book business called www.bookywooky.ie.

I insisted my web dev co to force customers to create / sign in to an account prior to creating a book so they wouldn't lose any of their work while customising it.

This has turned out to be a huge mistake (based on analytics) and I need to remove it asap.

Can anyone give a step by step account of how to do this? I've looked in 'Customer Configuration under System' but I can't see it.

I'm new-ish to Magento's back end and I can't find how to disable this step. Any advice in plain talk would be appreciated.

Cheers
Ross

Answer (score 0):

To disable guest checkout:
On the Admin sidebar, click Stores.

In the Settings section, choose Configuration.

In the Sales section in the left panel, choose Checkout.

Expand the Checkout Options section.

If necessary, clear the Use system value checkbox.

If the setting is for a specific store view, choose the store view where the configuration applies. When prompted, click OK to continue.

Set Allow Guest Checkout to “Yes”.

Click Save Config.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing your site I see that login is forced upon an attempt to add to cart. Out of the box, there is no configuration in the admin that enforces this. It is possible that the developer of your site may have decided to use the on/off setting "Disable Guest Checkout". However this is clearly a customization added via some level of code changes.

If your developer has not chosen to use this on/off feature, and not chosen to add a (new) on/off setting for this in the admin, then code changes will be necessary in order to disable this feature you have had added to your site.